# Python lambda with double loops

Tags: python, lambda

Is it possible to rewrite the following code into a lambda expression?

```
for h in range(height):
    for w in range(width):
        if maskImg[h][w] > 0:
            maskImg[h][w] = srcImg[h][w]
```

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: @tzaman To speed up?

Comment: Lambda expressions don't generally make things faster just like that.

Comment: If you want to speed up your mask operation, you may want to look into using numpy for fast element-wise multiplication.

Comment: In CPython, lambdas often make your code slower, not faster, unless you are using a built-in module that capitalizes on them. Comprehensions and loops generally win out in terms of speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really equivalent to you expression since this is not in-place, but you achieve the same end matrix using something like:

```
lambda_function = lambda height, width, src, mask: [[src[h][w] if mask[h][w] > 0 else mask[h][w] for w in range(width)] for h in range(height)]
```

But I would not recommend using it, ever. If you're after speed you should definitely use [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) for these kinds of things. Assuming that your `src` and `mask` are stored in Python-lists, you get the same result much, much faster doing:

```
import numpy as np
src_np = np.array(src)
mask_np = np.array(mask)
mask_np[mask_np > 0] = src_np[mask_np > 0]
```

Which on my computer is ~50 times faster than your solution.